# undefined return in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why the does following Javascript function return "undefined" in alert.

here is the snipptet

```
var tests = validateUserSelectedExperType(userSelectedOptioName);
alert(tests);
```

Code

```
function validateUserSelectedExperType(inp) {
    $.each(splitter.getFirstPaneContent(), function (index, item) {
        var splitterinner = splitter.getFirstPaneContent()[index];
        var getLabel = splitterinner.getFirstPaneContent()[0];
        if (getLabel.getText() == inp) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning from the nested function, not from the `validateUserSelectedExperType` function. Set a boolean and update that value instead. At the end, return it:

```
function validateUserSelectedExperType(inp) {
    var flag = false;
    $.each(/* ... */, function (index, item) {
        // ...
        if (getLabel.getText() == inp) {
            flag = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: You may also find looking at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/k4ZLP/) useful. It's basically an isolated equivalent of what you're doing.

Comment: This way `flag` will contain just the last iteration check result. Previous iterations are useless.

Comment: @0x499602D2 better, but break seems useless too, within a `if` statement. If you want to break `each` loop you should use `return false;`

Comment: _We can break the [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each) loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration._

Comment: @0x499602D2.. i got this error message "break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch" when i follow ur code..

Comment: @user1030128 Oops, I meant `return`. Please switch that.

Comment: As Andreas points out, `return` itself does nothing meaningful (the iteration will continue to the next element as usual). You need to `return false` to break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `return` statements are within `$.each()` anonymous function. Returning `false`from that function will stop the `each` loop.

You have to return something for the main function (I can't understand your code logic, so I can't help you in that).